# Is there a MATLAB function to do k-means clustering with a maximum value for k determined by a distance threshold?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have a large number of points that I would like to reduce to around some value N while maintaining reasonable diversity across the entire set. My thinking is to do a k-means clustering (with k=N) on the set of points, and then choose the "best" point from each cluster to be retained in the reduced set.

My problem is that sometimes the points are extremely concentrated in areas, and it doesn't really make sense for me to retain two points that are closer than say 10^-4, so I would like to give it the flexibility to let k < N, if it is the case that the clusters are too close together - or, better still, force any points that are closer together than some threshold to be in a cluster together, thereby potentially breaking up some of the other clusters with points that are further apart from each other, as it tries to maximise the number of clusters.

Is there a parameter setting for k-means in MATLAB, or a completely different function, that will let me do this? At the moment, I am just whittling the points down using the method I described above, and then doing a pairwise distance comparison on all the retained points to find sets of points that are too close, and then keeping the best points from those sets.

It works, but I thought it was worth seeing if there was already a function that does it better than my slightly hacky way.

I know about the "elbow method" for determining the optimal value of k for k-means clustering, but that doesn't really suit my purpose, as I am not interested in the optimal value for k, just the maximum value for k, such that k <= N, where the distance between clusters is greater than some threshold.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to do clustering on the cluster centers? :)

Comment: Look, there are [many different clustering algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cluster_analysis_algorithms). Why not look past the oldest, slowest, simplest clustering algorithm and try something better? I mean, the reason you learn about k-means in school is because the algorithm is easy to explain and implement, not because it is good.